# Retain the page update by Javascript and run the PHP code?

Tags: php, javascript

In a php project I need to add items to database, list them & allow the user to edit & update items using a single page.

This is my code to edit item link in HTML table

```
echo  '<a href="  '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?name=edit&id='  .$rowCountry->CountryId .' " id="edit"  onClick="MyFunction()"> Edit </a>';
```

When a user click on the above link I need to hide `Add` button and display two new buttons to `Update` & `Cancel` the edit +  display selected item name in a Text box to Edit.

To hide and display buttons I'm using jQuery and to display the item name i need to use PHP.
Here when i put PHP code and reload the page with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` (as in above code), hiding & displying of buttons is lost after the page load. (If I remove the `_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` code from link it hides and display buttons as expected (but no php code run))

How can I retain the page update by Javascript and run the PHP code?

I'm new to PHP am I missing something in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`  is only a refrence to the php document itself, it doesnt contain any key/value pairs. try using:

```
echo  '<a href="  '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'. $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].
    '&name=edit&id='  .$rowCountry->CountryId .
        ' " id="edit" onClick="MyFunction()"> Edit </a>';
```

edit:
    i may have misunderstood the question.  you may need something like this:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET[edit])){
    //echo code that u want to show AFTER they click the edit link
}else{
    //echo the code to show if they have NOT clicked the edit link
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Actually the PHP code runs fine, but the hiding of button is lost when page loads. (as I think its because, it runs the javascript client side-> hides buttons-> run php code in server-> loads the page from server-> button is back as it was).

Comment: you should only echo the buttons you need in php. you dont need to show/hide them with jquery... unless your using ajax?